# CORS preflight request works for me, but I still get CORS block for the next METHOD

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, cors

I have a cors problem the OPTIONS method works in the preflight but after that I get blocked by CORS on the following GET/POST request between my frontend and backend its a cross-origin

here is my CORS code in the backend what am I missing exactly for this to work?

```
const corsWhitelist = ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:5000", "https://www.myfrontendwebsite.com"];

const corsOptions = {
    origin: (originReq, callback) => { // Access-Control-Allow-Origin
        loggers.info("INSIDE CORSOPTIONS!!!! originReq!YES!!!!!");
        loggers.info(originReq); // the origin website name
        if (corsWhitelist.indexOf(originReq) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true); // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
        } else {
            callback(null, false); // disable CORS for this request
        }
    },
    // origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:5000", FRONTEND],
    credentials: true, //Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
    allowHeaders: ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Accept"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
};

app.options("*", cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

In my hosting LOGS I can see that the OPTIONS method is successful then after that the GET request is being blocked with this error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.backendwebserver.com/api/v2/login' from origin 'https://www.myfrontendwebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

**UPDATE**

First have two typos changed `optionSuccessStatus` to `optionsSuccessStatus` and `allowHeaders` -> `allowedHeaders`

Next the problem it wasn't working was in how I handled the `callback` inside origin

as I have in the if statement `callback(null, true)` I changed this `callback(null, { origin: true })` which has now fixed the problem

Comment: just to be sure, is all of this *before* you set up any routes? Middlewares are ordered, so e.g. if you `use('/api', apiRouter)` or `app.get('/some/path')` prior to this, it won't apply to those routes.

Comment: @EricHaynes yes it is at top level the only thing above this is morgan and winston and my database.authenticate function off sequelize ORM.

Comment: @EricHaynes if I set the origin to only 1 origin i have no problem but if i try to set a multiple whitelisting of multiple origin's is not working for some reason

this works: 
``origin: "https://www.onewebsite.com"``

this doesnt work
``origin: ["https://www.onewebsite.com", "https://www.twowebsite.com", "https://www.threewebsite.com"]``

why?

Comment: you say "*the OPTIONS method works in the preflight*" yet the error is telling you otherwise: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check`

Comment: You have a couple of typos in parameter names. Change `optionSuccessStatus` -> `optionsSuccessStatus` (options with an 's'). Change `allowHeaders` to `allowedHeaders`.

Comment: @EricHaynes Thanks I corrected that now. But apparently in the BIGGEST PROBLEM WAS IN THE ``callback`` inside the ``origin`` i should have done this ``callback(null, { origin: true });`` sending back in the 2nd parameter an object of ``{ origin: true }`` instead of just sending back true fixed the issue

Comment: @Mohamed - to be honest, the expressjs cors documentation is a little vague about what to return - easy mistake to make I'd say

Comment: Heh, I noticed that and was going to say something, but I had it in a TypeScript file, and the types are apparently incorrect: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a4df80cc8e40ad9448b83f923cd6c43133da56f5/types/cors/index.d.ts#L12-L14
Thus, it's a compile error to use what the docs have. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯